# Azure DevOps get all process fields

Tags: python, c#, azure-devops, wiql

Is there an api endpoint to get all the fields here?

[image: Fields]

I see that `wiql` only returns fields which have some value in them. Is there a `wiql` query for getting all the fields? There are like 60-70 of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks for both an API endpoint and WIQL. I can answer the API endpoint part of the question:

1. [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.2) - will get you the list of processes - use the `typeId` in subsequent calls.
2. [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{typeid}/workitemtypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes/%7Btypeid%7D/workitemtypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2) - will get you the work item types for that process - use the `referenceName` in the next call
3. [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{typeid}/workItemTypes/{referenceName}/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/work/processes/%7Btypeid%7D/workItemTypes/%7BreferenceName%7D/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2) will get you the list of fields - the `name` property should give you what you need.

To get all fields irrespective of process, use [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/wit/fields)

Comment: This is missing many fields e.g `Found in`, `How found`  `Found in Environment` etc. I still don't get how to get these fields for a particular work item with `WorkItemID`

Comment: I misread your question, but also, your question's screenshot asked fields for "All Processes". I've updated my answer to return that.

Comment: I need all the fields(in the picture) for a work item..is that possible?

Comment: You want the field definitions, or the field values? The last query I showed you shows what can be assigned - it's the full field set assignable to any processes' work items. The previous queries I showed show what is currently assigned to a work item type for a particular process. If you're asking about these fields' ***values*** in a work item, I think the answer might be "nothing" because they're not assigned to the work item's fields in the process?

Comment: What I mean to ask is. When I get Work Item field values..the API returns very few and onl y those which have some values. It is my understanding that work items will have almost as many fields as in the pic. Yes, looking for their values..for "existing" work items..including blank ones. I am using this. `https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/wit/workItems/376/updates?api-version=6.0`

Comment: I don't believe that a work item can show values for fields that haven't been assigned to the work item type in the process. That list you pasted is all field values defined across all processes and work item types. You're not going to get anything for these on your work items until you 1) assign them to the process and work item type, and 2) set values for them.